# scaling issue when using scypy's firwin2 to get coefficients for a filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, python

I am trying to use [SciPy's `firwin2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html) command to get the coefficients that correspond to a filter of my creating.  I took white noise in Audacity, applied an Equalization curve, exported said curve out of Audacity, and I am using `firwin2` to get the coefficients for said filter.  I manage to get coefficients out that give me a correct curve shape but the magnitude of the signal is WAAAAAAY off.  It's almost $50$ dB higher than what it should be.  Does anyone know when I could be leaving out a scaling factor?

Comment: probably should show your code